# ChartJS - Changing the padding of the labels in the legend adds padding to the top of the legend itself

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have this chart:

[image: ChartJS - legend - padding - not good]

But it's a bit ambiguous as to which color belongs to which label. So I decided to add a little padding to the labels. In [ChartJS documentations](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#legend-label-configuration) we have:

```
Name        Type    Default     Description
padding     number  10          Padding between rows of colored boxes.
```

So I double this number:

```
options: {
    legend: {
        position: "top",
        labels: {
            boxWidth: 5,
            usePointStyle: true,
            padding: 20
        }
    }
}
```

And I can see that it works:

[image: ChartJS - legend - padding - not good either]

But now it also adds padding to the top of the legend. To make the difference more noticeable, I'm going to exaggerate and set the padding to 50:

[image: ChartJS - legend - padding - exaggerated]

I'm trying add padding only between the labels of the legend, so that it's clear which box (colored circles) belong to which label. How can I do that?

Comment: Although there is no built-in way to only include horizontal padding for legend labels, you may be able to set a negative top padding value in the layout configuration: `options.layout.padding.top`

Comment: @Brian That helped, thanks

Comment: @AmirA.Shabani did you manage to find a solution for this?